# Extract messages from Alloy Analyzer

Tags: alloy

When you execute your Alloy-code in Analyzer you get some message like "No counterexample was found". And I want extract this message. I want, for example, get .txt file with this message. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This question is very broad. Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest and easiest way to do this would be to write a small java program that makes calls to the [Alloy API](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy-api/index.html) to analyze given models and write the result in a text file (example [here](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/code/ExampleUsingTheCompiler.java.html)).

Now if you want to choose the hard and dirty way, that is: to extract such information from the guenuine Alloy analyzer GUI (not from a program of your own that calls the Alloy API),I guess a solution could be to use image recognition scripting tools like [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).